# How do I solve the error "expected ')' before '->' token" in my code?

Tags: c, file, directory

First the code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

void printAttributes(de->d_name, &statBuff);

int main(){

    struct stat{
    } statBuff;

    int err;

    struct dirent *de;

    DIR *dr = opendir(".");

    if (dr == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open current directory");
        return 0;
    }

    while ((de = readdir(dr)) != NULL){
        err = stat(de->d_name, &statBuff);
        printf("%s\n", de->d_name);

        if(err == -1){
            printf("Error in Stat\n");
            printf("Press 'Enter' to continue\n");
            getChar();
            return 1;
        }

        printAttributes(de->d_name, &statBuff);
    }
    closedir(dr);
    return 0;
}

void printAttributes(de->d_name, &statBuff){
//function bs here
}
```

The compiler is saying the error is occurring on both lines 8 and 43 which obviously lead me to believe something is wrong with the function prototype/call but i cannot figure out what it is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `struct stat{
    } statBuff;` That is a tiny structure.

Comment: i think you have to understand better how to pass arguments to functions, you cannot pass `de->d_name` in `void printAttributes(de->d_name, &statBuff);`  but should be `void printAttributes(typeof name, typeof *stat);`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment, you've misunderstood the difference between a function definition, declaration and call
Take a look at this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_functions.htm

Also, as a general tip for both debugging stuff you don't understand and asking for help:
Try to make the example as short and simple as possible.
I usually find that in the process of simplifying, I find the error I'm looking for.